# PhoneGap, Play Audio, Stop Audio

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I have created a mobile application using phonegap. I planned to create two buttons, one to play the sound and another one to stop the sound. i tried several methods but none worked. I tried using code stated below, but didn't work also.

Javascript:

```
function playAudio(src) {
    if (device.platform == 'Android') {
        src = '/android_asset/' + src;
    }

    var media = new Media(src, success, error_error);

    media.play();

}

function success() {
    // ignore
}

function error_error(e) {
    alert('great error');
    alert(e.message);
}

function stopAudio() {
 if (media) {
 var media = new Media(src, success, error_error);
     media.stop();
     }
}
```

HTML:

```
<button onclick="playAudio('BackgroundMusic.mp3') "id="play" ></button>
<button onclick="stopAudio()"id="pause" ></button>
```

Can anyone help me to sort this out?

Comment: Have you add phonegap script (<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.0.0.js"></script>), have you add media permision <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" /> ?. is it src correct? / is a mp3 file?

Comment: Yes i have added. I am using mp3 sound file..i am using phonegap version 3.3.0. Still play button and stop button not functioning. What should i do now?

Comment: To be more precise i am using android version 4.1.2. If i use phonegap version to 3.3.0, <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.0.0.js"></script> and <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />. Sound cannot be played at all. On the other hand, if i use phonegap version 2.9.0 and <script src="phonegap.js"></script> , the sound can be played just that the stop button is not functioning. I really need someone to guide me.

Comment: In prevoius version of phonegap there was a problem with word media. Try to change it to my_media.   https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/8xtCB1eg9y0

Comment: Hey. i changed to my_media and it works really fine. Thanks for the help. My new problem is when i press play button several times, it tends to play sound many times thus echos can be heard. How can i prevent this from happening?